# Click to insert value into a input of a PHP form

Tags: php, html, sql

I have created a table with a mix of SQL, HTML and PHP.
See code:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Activated by:</th>
                <th>Serialnumber:</th>
                <th>Timestamp:</th>
                <th>Total consumed energy in kWh:</th>
                <th>Total bought enery in kWh:</th>
                <th>Energy left in kWh:</th>
            </tr>
            <?php

if ($serialresult) {
    while ($serialrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($serialresult)) {
        $serialnumbers = $serialrow['serial_number'];
      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Smartmeterlist WHERE serial_number='$serialnumbers'";
        $statsresult = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if ($statsresult) {
            while ($statsrow1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statsresult)) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM timeframe WHERE times = (SELECT MAX(times) FROM timeframe WHERE serial_number='$serialnumbers')";
                $statsresult = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                if ($statsresult) {
                    while ($statsrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statsresult)) {
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $statsrow1['activated_by'] . "</td> <td>" . $serialnumbers . "</td><td>" . $statsrow['times'] . "</td><td>" . $statsrow['consumed_energy'] . "</td><td>" . $statsrow['bought_energy'] . "</td><td>" . $statsrow['diff_energy'] . "</td></tr>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

}
?>

Below I create a form to execute an action:

```
        <div class="page-content">
        <form action="includes/distributeenergy.inc.php" method="POST">
            <input type="Number" step="0.01" name="serial_number"
                placeholder="Serial number"> <br> <input type="Number" step="0.01"
                name="distribute_energy" placeholder="Assign your energy"> <br>
            <div class="row">
                <input class="btn" type="submit" name="DE-btn" id="DE-btn"
                    value="Distribute">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

In the table are so called serial numbers of electronic devices.
I want to be able to click on a serial number (hyperlink or similar) and the serial number is used directly as an input for the form. So it is inserted into the "search bar".

Is there a simple way to realize this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Make the links point to your search form page, and append the serial number as a GET parameter. On the form page, check if a value was passed for that parameter (`isset` or `empty`), and if so, output that into the `value` attribute of the input field. Apply `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS attacks. Pretty basic stuff … if you need details on any of the mentioned keywords, then please go and try to research them on your own first.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try :)